# How to pass childcontent to a component in a bunit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, razor, bunit

My component allows for childcontent with a parameter:

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get { return m_ChildContent; } set { m_ChildContent = value; } }
```

The value is then used in the following way:

```
    <CascadingValue Value="this" Name="PopupParent" IsFixed="true">
      @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
```

Child content can be passed on:

```
    <ContainerComponent>
      <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
    </ContainerComponent>
```

However, when used in a bunit test the ChildContent section is left empty:

```
        var popup = Render(@<ContainerComponent Visible="true"><ChildComponent /></ContainerComponent>);
```

Or in a C# file the whole markup remains empty:

```
      var ctx = new TestContext();
      var childContent = ctx.RenderComponent<ChildComponent>();
      var container = ctx.RenderComponent<ContainerComponent>(parameters => parameters
        .AddChildContent(childContent.Markup)
      );
```

Note that the `childContent.Markup` does have a bunch of content.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: It looks correct what you are doing, and it is definitely supported, so not sure what’s going on. See  https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/passing-parameters-to-components.html?tabs=csharp#childcontent-parameters

Comment: I used simple HTML now, instead of another component. And that does work.